# Which AFDX connections are used in Airbus A380?

Tags: avionics, ima

AFDX is defined by ARINC 664 Part 7 and used in Airbus A380, I would like to know in which connections on the aircraft is used and for which purposes? Does anyone knows the answer or good documentation from which to start a research about?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Are you asking what type of devices are connected together on the aircraft's network via A664?

Comment: @scotty3785 I really mean any kind of connection, the point is I'm interested in study its usage on Airbus A380 and I will need to understand where is used. An example of answer I could expect it would be "It's used in the IFE infrastructure to connect LRU of the seats togheter or with the IFE Rack Server". I hope this explained a little bit my question.

Comment: I haven't seen any reference to the IFE system. Common sense would dictate that they systems would be partitioned from each other but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some resources.
[This source](http://www.artist-embedded.org/docs/Events/2007/IMA/Slides/ARTIST2_IMA_Itier.pdf) shows how AFDX is used as the backbone of the IMA (Integrated Modular Avionics) and lists subsystems such as the air data inertial reference units (ADIRU), Engine Electronic Controllers (EEC) and Electrical Load Management (ELM) Systems as 'members' of the network.

[This archived article](https://web.archive.org/web/20110719191449/http://www.rt.db.erau.edu/BLUE/team_bios/leo/Matos_AFDX_Term_Paper.pdf) talks about the development of AFDX to solve real time performance issues with the flyby wire controls of the A380.

Other articles of note would be [this](http://www.iject.org/vol4/spl4/c0140.pdf). The other articles are behind a paywall but for completeness they are [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4147050_The_Airbus_A380_-_an_AFDX-based_flight_test_computer_concept) and [here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1436931/?reload=true)

Comment: Please send me also the link of the articles behind pay wall, in case of need is better to have them and I will decide if they worth the value. Thanks.
Of course I mean the names of the articles in case you cannot send to me the effective links.

Comment: @Bluephoenix I've added the links that I was able to find.

Comment: @Bluephoenix You're welcome.

Comment: I finally add time to go through all the documents, one of them in the wayback machine is actually empty and the sources are unreachable, the other one are really useful and well made though they talk about the IMA and AFDX but not really mentioning where actually is used on an Aircraft.
Have I to suppose that in case AFDX is used together with IMA Architecture it connect everything and no other ARINC protocols are used in the Aircraft Network?

Comment: For example there is something in the Passenger Domain that is connected through the AFDX ( for example: SDU, FDB or IFE rack/terminal/server).